# Question looking for specific literature to read is not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, voting

I don't agree that this is a duplicate. [Where can I find Lovecraft books in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/where-can-i-find-lovecraft-books-in-esperanto)
It is hard enough to find books in Esperanto that forcing people to write to the official libraries and ask (!) is a very discouraging option.
It is worth pointing out that the other question is about the mere existence of a translation, no matter if one can buy it or if it has been translated. Actually reading it adds another dimension.
If there was a good database where you can search, find and download or buy the books right away, I wouldn't say this.
In this case it would make sense to answer with.... "going through the sources in the other question, I found nothing, nothing and nothing..." Isn't it somewhere out there?
And answer could be "I recommend this German book club, they have it, buy it there."
Normally we don't just want to "find out if a book has been translated" - we'd like to read it, too! We are here to help each other.
And seeing as Amazon has a lot of untrustworthy sellers (see Andrew woods' response to that question), it makes sense to go here and ask if we want to find a certain book.
If it ever changes, so that looking for and finding a book is easy "justgoogleit.com, letmegooglethatforyou" - this question becomes a duplicate.

I'm posting this here on meta because there are going to be more questions about specific literature. It makes sense to have a meta answer on this for the future.

Comment: Cast a reopen vote, and the question will go in the review queue for the questions to reopen.

Comment: Plus, the question is not marked as duplicate.

Comment: That's what I did and that's why it isn't marked as a duplicate anymore.

Comment: It isn't marked as duplicate because users reviewed it in the review queue.